# Obtaining all possible compositions of functions in mathematica

Tags: function-construction

Suppose I have two functions $f,g$ given by

```
f[path1_] := Drop[FoldList[fr[#1, #2] &, 1, path1], 1]
g[path1_] := Drop[FoldList[fr[#1, #2] &, -1, path1], 1]
```

with

`fr[z1_, z2_] := z /. FindRoot[f0[z] == z2, {z, z1}]`

and `f0[z_] := z^2 + c0`

with `c0=-1`

taking as input a list `list1 = Table[4E^(j*I*Pi/256), {j, 0, 512}]`.

Is there a way to write a function say `x[n_]` which gives all possible n-fold compositions of these two functions?

So `x[2]` would give the list `{f[f[list1]], f[g[list1]], g[f[list1]], g[g[list1]]}`

Could I then build some labeling of these? Suppose I wanted each composition to be labelled by the string  of functions that built it e.g. for the `f[g[g[list1]]]`  it would be labelled by $ggf$. Could I somehow also have a function that takes as input `x[2]` and gives the list `{ff,fg,gf,gg}` so as to keep track of the order of the output of `x[n]`?

I have been thinking about this for a while but it seems like a difficult code to write, although I do not have strong programming skills.

Comment: `#[list1] & /@ Composition @@@ Tuples[{f, g}, 2]`

Comment: Your question does not indicate how you are using `FindRoot`. What is the definition of your `fr`?

Comment: Which then leads to the question, what is your definition of `f0`?

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

c0 = -1;
f0[z_] := z^2 + c0;
```

Your use of [`FindRoot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html) indicated a possible precision issue. Consequently, add a means of precision control. Also, since `fr` uses a numeric technique, restrict its arguments to numeric values.

```
fr[z1_?NumericQ, z2_?NumericQ,
  wp_ : MachinePrecision] := Module[{
   z1p = SetPrecision[z1, wp],
   z2p = SetPrecision[z1, wp]},
  z /. FindRoot[f0[z] == z2p, {z, z1p},
    WorkingPrecision -> wp]]
```

Specify a `WorkingPrecision` in the definitions of `f` and `g`

```
f[path1_List] :=
  Drop[FoldList[fr[#1, #2, 15] &, 1, path1], 1];
g[path1_List] :=
  Drop[FoldList[fr[#1, #2, 15] &, -1, path1], 1];

x[n_Integer?Positive] := Module[
   {t = Tuples[{f, g}, n]},
   Transpose[{StringJoin @@@ (Map[ToString, #, {1}] & /@ t),
     #[list1] & /@ Composition @@@ t}]];
```

Using an abbreviated list for this example

```
list1 = Table[4 E^(j*I*Pi/256), {j, 0, 7}];
```

Using `N` to abbreviate the output display

```
x[2] // N

(* {{"ff", {1.41421, 1.55377, 1.59805, 1.61185, 1.61612, 1.61744, 1.61785, 
   1.61798}}, {"fg", {1.41421, 1.55377, 1.59805, 1.61185, 1.61612, 1.61744, 
   1.61785, 1.61798}}, {"gf", {-2.98023*10^-8, -1., -0.00012207, -0.999939, \
-0.00781262, -0.996086, -0.0625617, -0.968214}}, {"gg", {-2.98023*10^-8, -1., \
-0.00012207, -0.999939, -0.00781262, -0.996086, -0.0625617, -0.968214}}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it's very helpful, but there is something which doesn't act as it should. When I tried the code there was the same precision error. I have code which works to produce the list of outputs expected but this does not match the above code. The output should give complex numbers for example, `x1[0] = Map[ToComplex, ReIm[list1]]; x1[n_] := x1[n] = f[x[n - 1]]` and similarly we can define a recursive function for g. This gives the correct output but I had issues iterating this correctly, previously and it resulted in precision errors. I'm not sure if there is some way to fix this.

Comment: I do not understand your comment. `ToComplex` is undefined. Your recursion is not recursive. Although perhaps you mean for `x[n-1]` to be `x1[n-1]`. Please spend some time formulating questions.